# Does docusign gives an "upload signature" option to the recipient?

Tags: docusignapi

I am currently using a sandbox account in order to create a document and send an envelope. As a recipient, there are options to select style and draw the signature. However, there is no option to upload signature.
Is it because I am using a sandbox account, and the production account will have this option?
Edit 1: To be more specific, when a recipient receives the envelope for signing ceremony, there is no option for the recipient to "upload signature".[see screenshot of signing ceremony doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpjh2.png)

Answer (score 2):

This option does exist in there. When you log to your sandbox, click "Preferences" from the top right menu. then click "Signatures" and click "Edit" on one of them:
[image]

Comment: recipient must log in to DocuSign in order to use this option. Maybe that's the confusion

Comment: Thanks @inbar for response. The issue we are facing is when a recipient receives the envelope for signing ceremony, there is no option for the recipient to "upload signature". See screenshot of signing ceremony doc https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpjh2.png

Comment: yes, they have to first create their DocuSign account/user and sign in to get this feature. It's not given to recipients as part of signing if they're not members of the DocuSign network.

Comment: @InbarGazit: I am able to use this feature in sandbox environment where in users/recipients are not required to have their account created in DocuSign, but they can still upload their signature during signing ceremony.

Comment: yes, Saket, but are you doing this via the API? the API cannot do things on behalf of users who are not in the system

Comment: @InbarGazit: No, not through the API. I could find an option to enable it in settings in Admin UI. I have also posted it as answer below. Please check if anything is wrong in my understanding.

Comment: well, since this is a developer forum, I assumed that's what they are asking about

Comment: Upload the Signature at the time of signing is not auto enabled in the account. So you might need to contact your DS Account Manager to enable it in your DS Account (if it is not enabled). Demo (Developer Sandbox) Account has lot of settings which are enabled by default to make developers learn those features but many times you will not see those features in the PROD DS Accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Login with your admin credentials to your sandbox account. Click on your profile image and "Go to Admin" settings.

[image: Admin Settings]

Under "Signing and sending" section, click on "Signing Settings". Then navigate to "Signature Adoption Configuration". Make sure that "Disable upload signature" checkbox is not selected:

[image: Signing Settings]

Note: I am using sandbox environment and all users, without having their account created in DocuSign, is able to upload their signature during signing ceremony.

Comment: There's no issue I guess. Whatever the OP is trying to achieve, can be done in Sandbox environment by changing the setting provided in this answer.